# Ultra filter powers in the stone cech compactification

Tags: general-topology, ramsey-theory

Is it possible to define power of ultrafilters $p^q$ in the Stone-Cech compactification?
I tried to use the limit of $p^n$ when $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).